# Reactjs displays users info serially going up irrespective of the user clicked

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs displays users info serially going up irrespective of the user clicked.

I have 5 users in the array.

The code below was meant to display each Person Id and Name uniquely on their various popup box when their corresponding name 
in the list button is clicked.

**Here is my problem:**

My issue is that if I click for instance on user 1, instead of getting content of user 1 displayed on its own popup box 
it will display content of user 5.

If I pick another user randomly for example user 3 from the list, instead of getting the content of user 3 displayed on its
own popup box, it will display content of user 4 and next click of any user will display content of user 3 and so on going up to user 1.

Is this problem caused from person.id alignment or from serial alignment of users info in the array list?. can someone help me out

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      showBox: false,
data: [
        { id: "1", name: "user 1" },
        { id: "2", name: "user 2"},
        { id: "3", name: "user 3"},
  { id: "4", name: "user 4"},
  { id: "5", name: "user 5"},
      ],
    };

    this.showBox = this.showBox.bind(this);
    this.closeBox = this.closeBox.bind(this);
  }

showBox = (pid, name) => {

this.setState({ person_id: pid });

const dataSet = this.state.data;
alert(dataSet);
  if ($.inArray(pid, dataSet) != -1)
   {
dataSet.splice($.inArray(pid, this.state.data), 1);

    }
    dataSet.unshift(pid);
      var s = 270 ; // start position
    var j = 260;  //next position

    $.each(dataSet, function( index, value ) {  
       if(index < 4){
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').css("right",s);
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').show();

         s = s+j;   

       }
       else{
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').hide();
       }
    });
//event.preventDefault();


    //event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showBox: true }, () => {

     document.addEventListener('click', this.closeBox);
    });

  }

  closeBox(event) {

    if (this.cBox.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({ showBox: false }, () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeBox);
      });   

    }
  }
  render() {


    return (
      <div >


          <ul  style={{float: "right"}}>
            {this.state.data.map((person) => (

              <div  className="chat-sidebar" key={person.id}>

                <button onClick={ () => this.showBox(person.id, person.name)}>
                 {person.name} </button>




        {this.state.showBox 
            ? (



<div  rel={person.id} className="msg_box" style={{right: '270px',position: 'fixed', bottom:'-5px', width:'250px',background: 'white',borderRadius:'5px 5px 0px 0px', height: '200px'}}>

<div> <div style={{background: 'red',height: '150px'}}>
<div ref={(element) => {this.cBox = element;}} style={{color: 'blue'}}>Close</div>


Each Users info will appear here below.<br />
(person Id: {person.id})<br />

(person Name: {person.name})<br />



</div>
</div>           
</div>
            ): (
              null
            )}



</div>

            ))}
          </ul>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Screenshot updates**
[image: screenshot]

**Updated Code as Requested by Sir Win**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

class User extends React.Component {

  open = () => this.props.open(this.props.data.id, this.props.data.name);

  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div key={this.props.data.id}>
          <button onClick={() => this.open(this.props.data.id,this.props.data.name)}>{this.props.data.name}</button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class OpenedUser extends React.Component {
  close = () => this.props.close(this.props.data.id);




  render() {

    return (

      <div style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>

  <div onClick={this.toggle} className="msg_head">
                    (<b style={{ color: 'orange' }}>
                      Minimize
                    </b>)

          <button onClick={this.close}>close</button>
          <div>user {this.props.data.id}</div>
          <div>name {this.props.data.name}</div>

<div className="msg_wrap"><div className="msg_body">Message will appear here</div></div>
</div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

class ChatReact extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
    shownToggle: true,
      activeIds: [],
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: "user 1" },
        { id: 2, name: "user 2" },
        { id: 3, name: "user 3" },
        { id: 4, name: "user 4" },
        { id: 5, name: "user 5" }
      ]
    };
  }


  open = (id,name) => {
alert(name);
alert(id);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      activeIds: prevState.activeIds.find((user) => user === id)
        ? prevState.activeIds
        : [...prevState.activeIds, id]
    }));
  }

  close = id => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      activeIds: prevState.activeIds.filter((user) => user !== id),
    }));
  };

  renderUser = (id) => {
    const user = this.state.data.find((user) => user.id === id);
    if (!user) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <OpenedUser data={user} close={this.close}/>
    )
  }




  renderActiveUser = () => {
    return (
      <div style={{ position: "fixed", bottom: 0, right: 0  }}>
        {this.state.activeIds.map((id) => this.renderUser(id)) }
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
  var hidden = {
      display: this.state.shownToggle ? "block" : "none"
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(person => (
          <User key={person.id} data={person} open={this.open} />
        ))}
        {this.state.activeIds.length !== 0 && this.renderActiveUser()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. To get around this problem, I would use `.find` instead of $.inArray so that we can filter down the data into one result so that we can use it to display the information in the info box.

Avoid using `document.addEventListener` and `document.removeEventListener` and rely purely on state. If you're trying to achieve something not listed in the question, then please explain.

Also, try and avoid using jQuery with React.

Here's an example:

```js
class User extends React.Component {
  open = () => this.props.open(this.props.data.id);
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div key={this.props.data.id}>
          <button onClick={this.open}>{this.props.data.name}</button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class OpenedUser extends React.Component {
  close = () => this.props.close(this.props.data.id);
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
          <button onClick={this.close}>close</button>
          <div>user {this.props.data.id}</div>
          <div>name {this.props.data.name}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      activeIds: [],
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: "user 1" },
        { id: 2, name: "user 2" },
        { id: 3, name: "user 3" },
        { id: 4, name: "user 4" },
        { id: 5, name: "user 5" }
      ]
    };
  }

  open = id => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      activeIds: prevState.activeIds.find((user) => user === id)
        ? prevState.activeIds
        : [...prevState.activeIds, id]
    }));
  }

  close = id => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      activeIds: prevState.activeIds.filter((user) => user !== id),
    }));
  };
  
  renderUser = (id) => {
    const user = this.state.data.find((user) => user.id === id);
    if (!user) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <OpenedUser data={user} close={this.close}/>
    )
  }

  renderActiveUser = () => {
    return (
      <div style={{ position: "fixed", bottom: 0, right: 0  }}>
        {this.state.activeIds.map((id) => this.renderUser(id)) }
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(person => (
          <User key={person.id} data={person} open={this.open} />
        ))}
        {this.state.activeIds.length !== 0 && this.renderActiveUser()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir Win for your response but your solution uses toggling method instead of displaying each users info in a popup box. If you can test my code, you can see that when you click on each user  from a  list, a popup chat box containing the users info is supposed to be showed at the bottom of the page.  If you can refer to the issue am having as being posted, you can be able to understand it better. Between thank you so much, hoping to hear from you soon.

Comment: Thank you Sir Win for your response. It partly working now as its showing just one popup chat box. If I select two users instead of seeing two popup chat  box that corresponds to those two user. its showing just one box. I have added a screenshot on my post of how my code above displays all those chatbox like in facebook chat. Please can you help me further.  Between Thanks and hoping to hear from you Sir

Comment: @jmarkatti look at the updated answer, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir Win. This is the best solution ever in the history. its working great but in the console am seeing warning message.  please can you help me resolve this warnings in the console: bundle.js:5079 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `App`. 
    in OpenedUser (created by App. I cannot wait  to mark this solution as the best in the world. still counting on you Sir Win...

Comment: @jmarkati that is because your data is missing a key for each iteration. In your map make sure your parent JSX element has a key, for example I have used person.id. Update your question with your code if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you Sir Win for your amazing effort in getting me moving forward. I have updated my post to reflect the code as the warning keeps appearing in the console. please can you see section titled: Code Updated as requested by Sir Win. Hoping to hear from you Sir.Between thanks so much

Comment: @jmarkatti try to replace `<OpenedUser data={user} close={this.close}/>` with `<OpenedUser key={user.id} data={user} close={this.close}/>`

Comment: And `<div style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>`  with `<div key={this.props.data.id} style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>` sorry I am on my phone

Comment: Thanks so much Sir Win. You are the best in the world. Please Sir I have a requirements to add hide and unhide message div at my new post with your codes updates. please can you also assist me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54641059/reactjs-not-responding-to-div-toggling   Thanks