# Reactjs not responding to Div Toggling

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs not responding to Div Toggling

Am trying to **hide and unhide** div of a message box as per code below and it works fine as I can hide and unhide message div

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class Toggling extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shown: true,

    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
    });
  }
toggle() {
        this.setState({
            shown: !this.state.shown
        });
    }

  render() {
        var minimize = {
            display: this.state.shown ? "none" : "block"
        }

  return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <ul>
<div onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} style={{background: 'green'}}>Hide/unhide

            <div style={ minimize }> 

Chat content to be toggled or Minimized<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

</div>
</div>
          </ul>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now in the code below, am trying to hide and unhide each div content on a message popup box but its not responding when 
clicked. can someone help me with that with the code below

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';



class User extends React.Component {

  open = () => this.props.open(this.props.data.id, this.props.data.name);

  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div key={this.props.data.id}>
          <button onClick={() => this.open(this.props.data.id,this.props.data.name)}>{this.props.data.name}</button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class OpenedUser extends React.Component {
  close = () => this.props.close(this.props.data.id);




  render() {

    return (


      <div key={this.props.data.id} style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>

  <div onClick={this.toggle} className="msg_head">
                    (<b style={{ color: 'orange' }}>
                      hide/unhide
                    </b>)

          <button onClick={this.close}>close</button>
          <div>user {this.props.data.id}</div>
          <div>name {this.props.data.name}</div>

<div className="msg_wrap"><div className="msg_body">Message will appear here</div></div>
</div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      shown: true,
      activeIds: [],
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: "user 1" },
        { id: 2, name: "user 2" },
        { id: 3, name: "user 3" },
        { id: 4, name: "user 4" },
        { id: 5, name: "user 5" }
      ]
    };
  }



toggle() {
        this.setState({
            shown: !this.state.shown
        });
    }


  open = (id,name) => {
alert(name);
alert(id);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      activeIds: prevState.activeIds.find((user) => user === id)
        ? prevState.activeIds
        : [...prevState.activeIds, id]
    }));
  }

  close = id => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      activeIds: prevState.activeIds.filter((user) => user !== id),
    }));
  };

  renderUser = (id) => {
    const user = this.state.data.find((user) => user.id === id);
    if (!user) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <OpenedUser key={user.id} data={user} close={this.close}/>
    )
  }




  renderActiveUser = () => {
    return (
      <div style={{ position: "fixed", bottom: 0, right: 0  }}>
        {this.state.activeIds.map((id) => this.renderUser(id)) }
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
  var minimize = {
            display: this.state.shown ? "none" : "block"
        }

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(person => (
          <User key={person.id} data={person} open={this.open} />
        ))}
        {this.state.activeIds.length !== 0 && this.renderActiveUser()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to further extract the toggling method, you can simply add a state in `OpenedUser`. Instead of controlling display with the state we can use a ternary to control what JSX is shown dependent on state.

e.g.

`this.state.value === true` ? `<div>Show if true</div>` : `<div>Show if false</div>`

In this scenario, instead of display the entire div but hidden we can just set the false statement to null so that no elements are rendered into the DOM.

Replace your `OpenedUser` component with the one below:

```
class OpenedUser extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hidden: false
    };
  }

  toggleHidden = () =>
    this.setState(prevState => ({ hidden: !prevState.hidden }));

  close = () => this.props.close(this.props.data.id);

  render() {
    return (
      <div key={this.props.data.id} style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
        <div onClick={this.toggle} className="msg_head">
          <b style={{ color: "orange" }} onClick={this.toggleHidden}>
            hide/unhide
          </b>
          <button onClick={this.close}>close</button>
          <div>user {this.props.data.id}</div>
          <div>name {this.props.data.name}</div>
          {this.state.hidden ? null : (
            <div className="msg_wrap">
              <div className="msg_body">Message will appear here</div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Sir Win. You are the best. I will go around the world singing your name.......God bless you....

Comment: Please Sir Win, I have another issue here. can you help me at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665827/reactjs-how-to-properly-fetch-each-users-record-from-database-on-pop-button-cli

Answer (score 0):

Try if this helps.

```
 <button onClick={this.open}>{this.props.data.name}</button>
```